# Why is there so much converting between image formats needed? (UIImage, CGImage, CIImage)

Tags: ios, uikit, core-image

I'm confused as to why so much converting between image formats is needed in iOS. For example, if I load a jpg into a UIImage and then want to do face detection on it, I need to create a CIImage to pass to the CIDetector. Doesn't this represent a hit in both memory and performance?

Is this some legacy thing between Core Graphics, Core Image and UIKit (and probably openGL ES but I don't work with that)? Is the hit trivial overall?

I'll do what I need to do but I'd like to understand more about this is needed. Also, I've run into issues sometimes doing conversions and get tangled in the differences between the formats.

---

**Update**

Ok - so I just got dinged again by my confusion over these formats (or the confusion OF these formats...). Wasted a half hour. Here is what I was doing:

Testing for faces in a local image, I created the needed CIImage with:

```
CIImage *ciImage = [image CIImage];
```

and was not getting any features back no matter what orientation I passed in. I *know* this particular image has worked with the `CIDetectorTypeFace` before *and* that I have run into trouble with the `CIImage` format. The tried creating the CCImage like this:

```
 CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
```

and Face Detection works fine. Arrgh! I made sure with `[image CIImage]` that the resulting CIImage was not nil. So I'm confused. The first approach just gets a pointer while the second creates a new CIImage. Does that make the difference?

Digging into the UIImage.h file I see the following:

```
// returns underlying CGImageRef or nil if CIImage based
@property(nonatomic,readonly) CGImageRef  CGImage; 

// returns underlying CIImage or nil if CGImageRef based
@property(nonatomic,readonly) CIImage     *CIImage;
```

So I guess that is the key - **Developer Beware**: test for nil...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in the conception. All of UIKit, CoreGraphics and CoreImage does three such fundamentally different things that there can't be a 'grand central unified image format'. Also, these frameworks cooperate well; that said, the conversion should be as optimized and as fast as possible, but of course image processing is always a relatively computationally expensive operation.